# Unable to Install Robot framework HttpLibrary.HTTP library for Python 2.7.14

Tags: python-2.7, pip, robotframework

I am trying to install `HttpLibrary`.HTTP Library for using `JSON` `assertion` keywords like `JSON Value should equal`. However when I try to install Library using

```
 pip install --upgrade robotframework-httplibrary
```

I get:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   robotframework-httplibrary (from versions:) No matching distribution
>   found for robotframework-httplibrary. My pip version is 10.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command instead if that does not work upgrade php version

```
pip install  robotframework-httplibrary
```

To upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

alternatively if that does not work you can download the zip folder from here https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary and then run the `setup.py`

This needs to be ran from the command prompt

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Username\Desktop\setup.py
```

Alternatively you could try to install it using powershell with the following command

```
PS> pip install --isolated robotframework-httplibrary
```

Comment: After running the command pip install --upgrade pip i got **Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)** and by running  pip install  robotframework-httplibrary I received the same error could not find a version that satisfies the requirement. Please help.

Comment: thanks @Wojtek I tried doing it but i got **C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)**

Comment: @sangram i have update my answer once again please have a look

Comment: thanks again. I tried to run it from PS this time I got **'Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/robotframew
ork-httplibrary /**. Anyways I am not trying it by using HTTP Library. I will use other library.

Comment: @sangram Have a look at https://github.com/asyrjasalo/RESTinstance its fairly recent it could be a good alternative to Httplibrary

Comment: sure. Appreciate your help :)